# Saving an array of dictionary coming from plist , with UserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults, plist

I need to save my array with UserDefaults because I want users have ability to add or delete rows them selves. I have a plist contains rows of dictionaries. I fill an array name countries with the rows on plist like this

```
var imageList = ["usaflag","gerflag","franceflag","jpflag","gerflag"]
var countries = [Country]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let urlPlist = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ListinFirstPage", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: urlPlist)
     do
    {
        countries = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle error
        print(error)
    }

   savePlaces()


  }
```

Now the Array countries contains my plist rows . (filled with data of rows and works fine). my problem is how to save this array in UserDefaults , as it is an array of dictionaries seems it is a little complicated. I did this like the codes in bottom but it throws a thread in app delegate.

I added this line in viewdidload to call save function

```
savePlaces()
```

and then here is my savePlaces function

```
 func savePlaces(){

    do
    {
        let placesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: countries, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(placesData, forKey: "places")
    print("Here is save function")
    }
    catch
    {
    print("SaveError")
    }


}
```

It seems that problem is because of  `countries` array which it is an array of dictionaries coming from plist, because when I change this line

```
let placesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: countries, requiringSecureCoding: false)
```

to this

```
let placesData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: imageList, requiringSecureCoding: false)
```

I mean I changed the countries to the imageList which is an array of strings , it works fine. I defined image list in first line

```
 var imageList = ["usaflag","gerflag","franceflag","jpflag","gerflag"]
```

so the problem is `countries` but I do not know why and I will really appreciate for any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot serialize `struct`s with `NSKeyedArchiver`.

In `Country` replace `Decodable` with `Codable` and use that to save the array

```
func savePlaces() 
{
    do {
        let placesData = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(countries)                 
        UserDefaults.standard.set(placesData, forKey: "places")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, seems exactly what I needed. Just one thing , I changed it the way you guide but it confronts this error : `Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred` and as you said I think I should change something in there `countries = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)`  right?

Comment: exactly in this line `let placesData = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(countries)`

Comment: Did you replace `Decodable` with `Codable` in `Country` as suggested?

Comment: Seems solved but give me a minue, yes I forgot to, it was my fault

Comment: Thank you very very much. very smart and very helpful, Just dont know how to thank you and appreciate your time. again sorry for delay it was something about my computer, It works very well by you guide, thanks again

Comment: Excuse me , and I am really sorry very much, but if no matter, please look at this question , I really  really appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465965/how-to-decode-data-of-an-array-that-is-save-and-read-from-userdeafults-swift