# How to decode data of an array that is save and read from userDeafults - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am working on a project that it has a plist contains of rows of dictionaries , and then , I put all the rows of datas to an array and I save it to the useDefaults and all these things seems correct , but in the read method , I understand that my data seems to be coded and it shows it in codes. like this `(6b756e74)` I wonder to know how I can decode my data in a very correct way. here is my codes

```
struct Country : Codable {
    let orFlagEmoji, destFlagEmoji : String

    private enum CointryKeys : String, CodingKey { case orFlagEmoji, destFlagEmoji }
}

var countries = [Country]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let urlPlist = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ListinFirstPage", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: urlPlist)


    do
    {
        countries = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
    }
    catch
    {
        // Handle error
        print(error)
    }
      savePlaces()
      readPlaces()
   }

   func savePlaces(){

    do
    {
        let placesData = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(countries)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(placesData , forKey: "places")

        return
    }
    catch
    {
    print("SaveError")
    }


}

func readPlaces()
{

    let loadedcart = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "places")

    print(loadedcart as Any)

}
```

The problem is that when I print `loadedcart` (that it should contains countries data) in console it seems data has been coded some how. the output is some numbers not my string data. I really appreciate if some one help me to make it correct. Thank you very much

Comment: Don't use UserDefaults. Just write your plist data to a file.

Comment: can you help me more by answering the question please? I really do not know what should to do exactly! @LeoDabus Thank you very very much.

Comment: You used `PropertyListEncoder` to convert `countries` to `Data` and you saved that data to `UserDefaults`. Do the opposite when reading. Your code so far gets back the `Data`. Now use `PropertyListDecoder` on that data.

Comment: @rmaddy oh thank you very very much seems helpful but can you please answer my question with more details? Really Really appreciate you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all delete `readPlaces`. It's pointless

```
func readPlaces()
{   
    let loadedcart = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "places")    
    print(loadedcart as Any)    
}
```

Delete also

```
private enum CointryKeys : String, CodingKey { case orFlagEmoji, destFlagEmoji }
```

because the keys are never used (not even correctly spelled `CountryKeys`).

---

Basically your code to load and save the data is correct, it's just misused.

Check if the key `places` in `UserDefaults` is empty. If so copy the data from the bundle

```
var countries = [Country]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
       try loadPlaces()
    } catch { print(error) }
}

func loadPlaces() throws 
{
    let data : Data
    if let placesData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "places") {
       data = placesData
    } else {
       let urlPlist = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ListinFirstPage", withExtension: "plist")!
       data = try Data(contentsOf: urlPlist)
       UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "places")
    }
    countries = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data) 
}

func savePlaces()
{
    do {
        let placesData = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(countries)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(placesData , forKey: "places")
    } catch {
        print("SaveError", error)
    }
}
```

Call `savePlaces` always after having modified `countries` (except in `viewDidLoad)`

As mentioned in the comments `UserDefaults` is not the right place to save a large set of data. A custom file in the `Documents` folder is preferable.

Comment: Hi and sorry to bother you again. I worked on the code you have suggested and I confronts a problem that is not very compatible with what I need exactly, and I really appreciate if you could help me in a update , this code you have suggested works completely fine, but is not exactly what I needed. I want to add some rows to the countries array and then save and read from this array. I mean plist is reading just once for the first time , and after that, countries should be saving and reading from

Comment: but in your code, in loadPlaces each time it reads datas of plist not countries and thats my exact problem. but You really did a lot for me and I really appreciate, you did alot . thank you

Comment: That's exactly what the code does. As I wrote in the answer *Call `savePlaces` always after having modified `countries`*. You must not call `loadPlaces()` right after saving the new data as `countries` contains the current data. The next time you launch the app the modified data is loaded. No, my code copies (reads) the plist data only on the very first launch of the app

Comment: Thank You very very much Vadian. Yeas I understand what you mean and works perfect. You did a lot. Thank you 10000.....0000 times